# How to solve incorrect return value of javascript+firebase function due to order of operation is different when retrieving data?

Tags: javascript, function, firebase, order-of-execution

I am currently implementing a javascript function to judge if user id and name matches or not.

```
function name_match(user_id, user_realname) {
    var dbref = firebase.database().ref();
    var namesref = dbref.child("names");
    namesref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(i => {
            if(i.key == user_id && i.child("realname").val() == user_realname) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
    return false;
}
```

However, regardless of input, it will initially return false. I think this is because it will go to "return false" while firebase data is loading.

So, even if eventually returns true, since the first-time return value is false, it causes a problem in like this (in another function).

```
function name_match2() {
    var user_id = document.getElementById("user-id").value;
    var user_realname = document.getElementById("user-realname").value;
    if(!name_match(user_id, user_realname)) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

And it will return -1.

Can you explain how to solve this problem?

Comment: Your function will always return false. The `return true` is for the anonymous function in your `forEach`. But this will never become the return value of `name_match`. Your issue is that firebase uses an async API which you are trying to use in a sync function. That's not possible, you need to change the whole design of this part of your application from sync to async.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained by Daniel in the comment, outer function never returns true. The async solutions could be these :)

```
function name_match(user_id, user_realname) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      var dbref = firebase.database().ref();
      var namesref = dbref.child("names");
      namesref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
          var matched = false;
          snapshot.forEach(i => {
              if(i.key == user_id && i.child("realname").val() == user_realname) {
                  matched = true;
              }
          });

          if (matched) {
             resolve()
          } else {
             reject()
          }
      });
    });
}
```

On the other side of calling function

```
name_match('userId', 'userName').then(function(){
//matched
}, function(){
//unmatched
});
```

Other way would be to use Callbacks:

```
function name_match(user_id, user_realname, cb) {
      var dbref = firebase.database().ref();
      var namesref = dbref.child("names");
      namesref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
          var matched = false;
          snapshot.forEach(i => {
              if(i.key == user_id && i.child("realname").val() == user_realname) {
                  matched = true;
              }
          });

          cb(matched);
    });
}
```

In this case:

```
name_match('userId', 'userName', function(matched) {
    console.log(matched);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small adaptation of Suryapratap solution, using the [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#once) method, which

1. "Listens for **exactly one event** of the specified event type, and then stops listening.", and
2. Returns a Promise

... instead of using the [`on()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#on) method which sets a listener.

```
function name_match(user_id, user_realname) {

      var dbref = firebase.database().ref();
      var namesref = dbref.child("names");

      return namesref.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
          var matched = false;
          snapshot.forEach(i => {
              if(i.key == user_id && i.child("realname").val() == user_realname) {
                  matched = true;
              }
          });
          return matched;
      });

}
```